# tvos 15 - Siri Remote not returning in the array: GCController.controllers()

Tags: swift, swiftui, tvos, gamecontroller, siri-remote

in **swiftUI** & **tvOS 15**, when calling the GCController.controllers() to get the list of controllers connected to the apple tv,

```
import GameController

 ...

let siriRemoteAsGameController = GCController.controllers().first
```

the Siri Remote is not registered as the first controller, in fact it is not registered at all !

up until tvOS 15 (14.7 for example) it was working

even if i register for notification the connect event isn't dispatched for the already connected Siri remote

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .GCControllerDidConnect, object: nil, queue: .main) { note in
        print("GCControllerDidConnect")
        if let detectedGCController = note.object as? GCController {
            print("Controller Detected")
        }
    }

GCController.startWirelessControllerDiscovery(completionHandler: {})
```

i cannot find a change in that area according to [Appel's $#itty documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/gccontroller/1458871-controllers)

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on [this answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691049?answerId=689396022#689396022) it seems that an interaction with the remote **after** calling (at least once) to `GCController.controllers()` is required so the solution was this:

```
import GameController

struct ContentView2: View {
  var body: some View {
    // first call before remote interaction
    let a = print("controllers: \(GCController.controllers())")
    
    Button("Query controllers") {
      // second call after a press button via remote interaction occurred
      print("controllers: \(GCController.controllers())")
    }
  }
}
```